# How to use http Response method Read in go?

Tags: go

It's been a while since I dealt with go and I seem to have forgotten how to read the docs.

If I do a get request like this...

```
resp, err := http.Get("https://example.com")
```

I then see that the response has a `Body` that is of an `io.ReadCloser` type (https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadCloser). I see the ReadCloser is an interface to `Reader` and `Closer`.

When I look at the `Reader` interface I see it has a `Read` method that reads bytes into `p` (https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader).

To recap, the http `Response` has a body which is a `io.ReadCloser` Interface which itself contains a `Reader` interface which has a `Read` method.

When I try this I would expect to `Read` the response bytes into HTML, but I see nothing...

```
var html []byte
num, err := resp.Body.Read(html)
fmt.Println("\n\thtml: ", html)
fmt.Printf("\n\tnum: %v, err: %v\n", num, err)
```

Output:

```
html:  []
num: 0, err: <nil>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to allocate space to read into. You're only providing a nil slice, so Read can't _read_ anything.

Comment: Read reads up to len(html) bytes into html , here it is zero

Answer (score 8, accepted):

short answer: You are passing a slice `html` where its len would be '0' and Read reads up to `len(html)` bytes into html

Here is snippet from https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader

> Read reads up to len(p) bytes into p. It returns the number of bytes
> read (0 <= n <= len(p)) and any error encountered. Even if Read
> returns n < len(p), it may use all of p as scratch space during the
> call. If some data is available but not len(p) bytes, Read
> conventionally returns what is available instead of waiting for more.

Now what you may do  use `ioutil` and update the code as

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
```

Code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://httpbin.org/ip")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error making request", err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading response", err.Error())
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Response\n", string(body))
}
```

Here is play [link](https://play.golang.org/p/9w9N2VK5iUJ), in go playground HTTP requests won't work it is a security precaution so you may test this in your machine

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "io/ioutil" package:

```
import "io/ioutil"
...
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
resp.Body.Close()
fmt.Println(string(body)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a good helper and friend [ReadAll()](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll)

Your code should looks like this:

```
import "io/ioutil"

resp, err := http.Get("https://example.com")
// check err

defer resp.Body.Close() // we have to close Body if we want to reuse the connection

html, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
// check err

fmt.Println(string(html))
```